# where should I store CSS files in a sharepoint install?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I have some css files that are deployed in a feature scoped to "site"

They contains some calls to images (also deployed by the solution) and so the paths are things like

```
background: #ffcc00 url(  '/sites/portal/Style Library/CSS/PersonalCenter.gif' ) repeat-x;
```

However I would quite like to be able to deploy to other "sites/XXXX" without having to change the url in all the css files!

I cannot just place them in the top level URL as it has its own styles etc and it would be confusing to mash styles from subs-sites into it.

Is there somewhere else I should be storing things like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers... In the end I have remembered about relative paths and

```
background: #ffcc00 url(  '../CSS/PersonalCenter.gif' ) repeat-x;
```

works just fine.

The images/css files remain in the Style Library which has been useful to check CSS changes before committing them to the main feature and doing a 'proper' release of the solution

Now why did I not just do that from the start !?

Answer (score 1):

How about placing them (the images) in _layouts, then you could use

```
url(  '/_layouts/images/PersonalCenter.gif' )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two major options for this:

**1. Store your images in the Style Library.**

Browse to /sites/portal/Style Library/Images and create a folder there to store your images. This appears to be similar to what is already being done in the CSS file. Use a relative path in the CSS file to avoid the /sites/portal part of the URL.

*Advantages:* Version control, no need to worry about deployment across multiple servers.

**2. Store your images on the file system.**

Create a folder for the images specific to your solution, e.g. at

> C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\siteXXX

This maps to the folder that Johan mentions where you would use

> /_layouts/images/siteXXX/image.gif

to reference your images.

*Advantages:* Performance (maybe) depending on how the server is configured.

**Recommendation:** Use the Style Library if possible. Version control alone is a huge benefit.